# Jquery not working on cshtml to pop up dialog box

Tags: c#, jquery, html

This is the editor for the startdate `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate)`  and I have jquery blow, the code for the query is on the page and when I run the program the calender pop up does not come up, both code are on the dame cshtml page

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#startDate" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: If you're using firefox, open your page and then see the error console(CTRL+SHIFT+J), any error?

Comment: Did you see any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: there was no errors in the browser consol

Comment: Can you post what is HTML generated for `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate)`? just view page source and find that element...

Comment: Can you try adding additional input element as text and adding the datepicker to that input tag. I could see your scripts are fine as they were in the datepicker documentation.

Comment: I know but i cant qadd them in as input elemnts as i even know it would work in this manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate)`

with

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate, new { @class="startDate" })`

because you have not giveen a class to that field and change your jQuery to

```
$(function() {
    $( ".startDate" ).datepicker();
  });
```

so `#` becomes `.` as we are using a class.

Comment: Have you added links to `jquery.ui.core.js
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.ui.datepicker.js` these files? and this one too `jquery.ui.datepicker.css`? If no, then add them and then it will work for sure.

Comment: i dont think i do where would i be able to find them from

Comment: Jquery official website..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that all your external scripts loaded properly. I suggest you install Fiddler and then watch your requests and see if all of them loaded. If that all is ok then you need to check that the scripts actually load before your call for the datepicker function. If you're using MVC 4 and sections feature that would mean that all you javascript code needs to go into the SCRIPTS section which is placed on your view AFTER the calls to load jquery and jquery-ui libraries. Use Goggle Chrome's console to verify that there are no javascript errors.

Looking at the code you posted here everything should be working. I've done this millions of times and every time I had a problem it was because I was missing a JQuery library reference or I wasn't loading them in proper order.